Why are there no Tehillim corresponding to earlier in David's life?
As far as I can tell Psalm 59 is the earliest explicit reference to events in David's life, corresponding to 1 Samuel 19. I would like to know if any commentaries explain why there are no Pslams which correspond to earlier events in David's life such as his anointment or battle with Goliath

It's certainly possible as a shepherd in his father's house he wasn't literate. It wouldn't surprise me he was taught after being ordained by Samuel and rising in status.

Yeah building on the point above, perhaps those moments later in his life simply became more pressing issues and the primary focus of his praises because they were more recent

He wouldn't have needed to be literate to play his harp and compose songs. Perhaps he took his earlier compositions and refined them when he got literate?
